# How to link to a single question/thread in Chatter

Tags: community, chatter

How can I link to a single question/thread in a Chatter group? I see no options for this.

I'd expect to be able to click on the subject line of the question and have that take me to a page that displays only that thread, and have that page have a unique URL that I can use to link to only that thread. That's how forum sites have worked for 15+ years. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Salesforce Classic or Lightning UI you can click on the date / time stamp and it will take you to a page with just that thread on it with a URL that will take you directly back to that thread.

Also in Lightning UI you can select "Share" then "Copy Link". This generates the same link as the above method.